# Файл в папке проекта не видит установленных модулей в виртуальном окружении PyCharm, python (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

При попытке запустить файл *который находится в папке проекта* через терминал *(или обычную консоль Windows, учитывая то что виртуальное окружение активировано)* появляется ошибка **ModuleNotFoundError**. (Использую редактор кода **PyCharm**)
Хотя если использовать **встроенный компилятор** кода всё работает.

Расположение папок и файлов в проекте: 
[image: Расположение папок в проекте]

Терминал в PyCharm с ошибкой: 
[image: Терминал в PyCharm с ошибкой]

Все необходимые модули установлены в виртуальное окружение python:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


def test_function():
    print(fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!"))


test_function()
```

Comment: А если не делать cd Test и вызывать `python3 Test\test_function.py` ?

Comment: Проверил, не помогло. Ошибка всё та же (ModuleNotFoundError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое чувство что интерпретатор не находит python3 в этом окружении и берет его из вне (возможно у вас установлено несколько версий питона). Попробуйте запустить

```
py test_function.py
```

или

```
python test_function.py
```

*Написал бы в комментарии но кармы пока не хватает*

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало с использованием команды: `py test_function.py`